# How to create file pdf file in google drive sdk using php

Tags: php, file, pdf, google-drive-api

I am creating a pdf file using google drive sdk but I got an error when the file is created.. I cant download the file.

this is my php code in creating the pdf file:

```
$subcontent = "<h1>Hello World</h1><p>text here of some</p>";
$file = new Google_DriveFile();

$file->setTitle( $fileName );

$file->setDescription( $description );

$mkFile = $this->_service->files->insert($file, array('data' => $subcontent, 'mimeType' => 'application/pdf'));
```

the file is cannot be download or print..
[image]

the file also have an error displayed on the bottom saying 
`Opps! There was a problem loading more pages`
[image]

can anyone help me in my case? I have been working on it in a week.. Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made an assumption that Drive will convert your HTML file into a PDF file. **It won't**.

What you can do is ask Drive to convert your HTML to a Google doc, and then export that doc as PDF. Change your mime-type to `text/html` and add `convert=true` (see the library docs for how to do this).